# How to send transaction using web3 contract instance from address which is not a node's account

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ganache

I succeeded creating transaction from node's account(created by ganache) to a contract using web3.js .

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
    from: from,
    gasPrice: 200000000
});
contract.methods.sendCoin(receiverAddress, '1').send() // succeeded
```

However, how to send transaction to a contract from address which is not node's account.

Does Contract Instance have any methods to sign transaction?? or, Contract Instance cannot be used to sign Transaction and need to use another way ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sign the transaction with the private key of the account, and then send it to the node.

For example (tested with Web3.js v1.2.1):

```
async function send(web3, privateKey, gasPrice, contract, receiverAddress, numOfCoins) {
    const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address;
    const transaction = contract.methods.sendCoin(receiverAddress, numOfCoins);
    const options = {
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account}),
        gasPrice: gasPrice
    };
    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    return receipt;
}
```

You can generalize this function by passing `transaction` to it as input instead of initializing this variable internally:

```
async function send(web3, privateKey, gasPrice, transaction) {
    ...
}

async function main() {
    ...
    const transaction = contract.methods.sendCoin(receiverAddress, numOfCoins);
    const receipt = await send(web3, privateKey, gasPrice, transaction);
    ...
}
```

Thus you can call it with any other transaction.

Comment: Thank you! your code worked.  Then, I want to ask one thing. What is transaction._parent._address and why is it neccesary ? I thought "to" is contract's address, but to is transaction._parent._address. why?

Comment: @engineerk: You're welcome. `transaction._parent._address` is indeed the contract address in all cases except for when the transaction is `contract.deploy(...)`, in which case, the contract doesn't have an address yet. So you can indeed simply use `contract._address` or `contract.options.address`.

Comment: But please note the suggestion for a more generalized function which I added at the bottom of the answer, where instead of passing the contract and the parameters of the function that you want to execute, you pass the transaction itself. In this case, you don't have the contract address at hand, hence `transaction._parent._address` becomes useful.

Comment: @engineerk: You're welcome (spelled "Great" I believe).

Comment: @engineerk: BTW, I think that those guys at Web3 dev team did not intend for `transaction._parent` or `transaction._parent._address` to be used at all (hence the underscore prefixes in those variable names). So it is possible that these variables will not be available in future versions of this module.